# Authentication and role authorization in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 4 framework, before I developed .NET web apps using ASP.NET Web Forms.

In my new project (I'm updating an existing Web Form project) I need to implement Form authentication and role based authorization to pages and functionalities.

Following some articles and StackOverflow answers I'm trying to use `SimpleMembershipProvider` but I'm finding several difficulties to configure it and in integration with my existing DB.
In particular cannot use my existing user accounts table...

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and now I'm upgrading from Linq-to-SQL to EntityFramework.

Can you suggest me the **best way to implement authentication and role authorization** in ASP.NET MVC4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how custom you need:
1) Try something, that exists already. As long as you're using EF, you may try https://efmembership.codeplex.com. Haven't tried it, but from first look, looks reasonable and configurable. There are also other MembershipProvider implementations on nuget gallery if previous one does not fit.
2) If really nothing fits into your scenario from existing in nuget gallery, implement membership provider by your self. Example may be here: http://blog.ianchivers.com/2012/03/entity-framework-custom-membership.html or there even video how to do it: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider